# Python service - get json body

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymysql

I have an endpoint that returns data based on user selection.
The user sends me these values :
Name, ID, Age, Gender.

Then I use pymysql to query a table where Name = given name, for received ID and Gender.

But how do I get these values in python ?

```
@app.route('/userInfo', authorizer=authorizer)
def data():
try:
    params = app.current_request.query_params or json_body?
except:
    pass

  // get individual fields and assign to variables?

  sql = "SELECT SurveyResult From UserInfo WHERE Name = %(name)s AND Gender = %(gender)s AND Age = %(age)s
```

And then

```
   cursor.execute(sql, { 'name': ? , 'gender': ? , 'age': ?
  input values here? })
```

What is the safest way to get request those values to the service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using flask, here is a way to get the params/post data

Note : you need to import request `from flask import request`

POST :

`name = request.form['name']`

GET :

`name = request.args['name']`

and then insert them

`cursor.execute(sql, (name, gender, age))`

remember to commit

`connection.commit()`

To make your life easier, consider using an ORM such as [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/)